# Where exactly should i add crossdomain.xml file?

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml, file-not-found

i am trying to create a internet radio....

I use icecast2 for streaming..... edcast plugin with winamp to send the music to icecast... and the xspf web music player (http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/) to connect the user to the icecast server and play the music....

The setup works great and i can broadcast and receive on the local network i use to test the radio.. using xampp...

Now the icecast broadcasts online from  a windows server with the ip address say xx.xx.xxx.xxx

The webpage in which the flash player is embedded is uploaded to www.xyz.com/images/radio

This domain has the same ip address from where the icecast server runs.

Now when i run the webpage to connect to the radio with the flash player, i get the error in firebug as

"xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8000/crossdomain.xml     404 NOT FOUND"

But i have created a crossdomain.xml file in the root of the xx.xx.xxx.xxx server... Still it doesn't recognize the file...

Can anyone tell me where exactly  i should create the file for my setting...???

Thanks a lot in advance.....

Comment: How is this programming related?

Answer (score 1):

Could the server you are connecting to be blocking that port? Or perhaps, can you reconfigure the flash player to use port 80? (HTTP which should be open)

**To be clear:** what you have done *should* work, the crossdomain.xml should happily sit in the root of the server.

The only other option I can think of it so host the Flash player itself on the server (which has the crossdomain), then update the HTML to reference the SWF there. This *might* work - but I wouldn't hold my breath (not a Flash expert). **Can you give that a try?**

Comment: I checked it.. i can still connect to it manually... just not through the flash player...

Comment: I'm not familiar with flash... But the flash player is open source... Can you tell me how i can edit the flash player...?

Comment: If it's open source, and you know AS, then grab the source and hack away! (based on the fact that you said you are not familiar with flash, I would guess not) - Most open source projects have a "discussion/issues" page - have you tried contacting them?

Comment: Yup... i've tried.. but the forums are dead now... I've tried to "hack open" :) the fla file... But couldn't figure out what's inside to save my life....

Comment: Ok, so to be clear, you have tried changing the URL for the Flash to use port 80 ("xx.xx.xxx.xxx:80) and there is nothing in the documentation to say how to change it? I would be surprised if it didn't work on port 80 :S

If no joy, then I am not sure what else to recommend - it may be dead for a good reason (i.e not supporting standards) - Different Flash player? :( (no recommendations I'm afriad)

Comment: Many professional websites use this player... It's vouched for it's performance... The way i see it the player is configured to look for the xml in xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8000 port and i can't figure out how to create the file in that place...

Answer (score 1):

**You get a 404/500/504/file not found Error:** This means that the crossdomain.xml is not where it should be, or can't be read by icecast.

On windows place crossdomain.xml in "C:\Program Files\Icecast2 Win32\web"
(on debian/ubuntu in /usr/share/icecast2/web/crossdomain.xml)

**You are prompted to download crossdomain.xml to your computer:** This means that your streaming server isn't serving crossdomain.xml file correctly. The most common scenario, is that icecast doesn't have right mime.types for xml and/or ogg/aac files.

Copy some apache mime.types file inside "C:\Program Files\Icecast2 Win32"

**You see the XML file inside your browser:** If this is your case, then crossdomain.xml is correctly installed and served. You should check XML file format and hosts restrictions.

on windows place crossdomain.xml in "C:\Program Files\Icecast2 Win32\web"
(on debian/ubuntu in /usr/share/icecast2/web/crossdomain.xml)